# std::begin and std::end not working with pointers and reference why?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Why **std::begin()** and **std::end()** works with array but not pointer[which is almost array] and reference of array [which is alias of original array].

After scratching my head for 15 min i am not able to get anything in google.

Below only first case works, not second and third, what could be the reason for this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
   int first[] = { 5, 10, 15 };  // Fist Case

    if (std::find(std::begin(first), std::end(first), 5) != std::end(first)) {
        std::cout << "found a 5 in array a!\n";
    }

   int *second = new int[3];  // Second Case
    second[0] = 5;
    second[1] = 10;
    second[2] = 15;
    if (std::find(std::begin(second), std::end(second), 5) != std::end(second)) {
        std::cout << "found a 5 in array a!\n";
    }

    int *const&refOfFirst = first;  // Third Case

        if (std::find(std::begin(refOfFirst), std::end(refOfFirst), 5) != std::end(refOfFirst)) {
        std::cout << "found a 5 in array a!\n";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int&)’
  if (std::find(std::begin(*second), std::end(*second), 5) != std::end(*second)) {
                                  ^
```

Comment: Your third case is reference to a pointer, not to an array.

Comment: Since when is a pointer "almost an array"?

Comment: @JamesKanze a pointer is half an array. In the same way that an iterators is half a range :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given just a pointer to the start of an array, there's no way to determine the size of the array; so `begin` and `end` can't work on pointers to dynamic arrays.

Use `std::vector` if you want a dynamic array that knows its size. As a bonus, that will also fix your memory leak.

The third case fails because, again, you're using (a reference to) a pointer. You can use a reference to the array itself:

```
int (&refOfFirst)[3] = first;
```

or, to avoid having to specify the array size:

```
auto & refOfFirst = first;
```

and `begin` and `end` will work on this exactly as they would work on `first` itself.

Comment: "Given just a pointer to the start of an array, there's no way to determine the size of the array; so begin and end can't work on pointers to dynamic arrays.", well, there is at least a `begin`. I have seen generic programming cases in which `T* begin(T* ptr){return ptr;}` would make sense to exist.

Comment: @alfC `begin` without `end` is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Caleth well, using a (single) pointer to describe a finite range is asking for trouble in the first place (OP question). In fact I don’t define an ‘end’ so you will get a compilation error eventually. My point is that you can still have generic code if what you need is a sentinel (see Rangesv3) rather than a normal end. (Some algorithms applied to an unended range are (can be) guaranteed to terminate even without and ‘end’.)