# C++ Pointer array to set using STL begin and end

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

I am learning C++ and stuck with one scenario where I have to convert array to set

I have pointer which holds the address of array and I want to get all unique elements of array into set . Using STL how its possible . Below is my code spinet and am also looking for good explanation .

```
#include<set>

void possiblepermutation(int *array) {
    set<int> roots(begin(array),end(array));

}
```

---

After reading below comment , I understood that as I am passing pointer so begin() and end() will have no idea about start and end . Can you help me what if I pass size of array along with array pointer , how to do.

```
void possiblepermutation(int *array , int n) {
        set<int> roots(begin(array),end(array)); // HOW TO THEN 

    }
```

Comment: "I am learning C++" => so don't tag C !

Comment: You need the esize of the array, because any size information is lost when you pass an array to a function.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. But `array` is just a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909429/stdbegin-and-stdend-not-working-with-pointers-and-reference-why

Comment: When learning C++, you might find a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::begin` and `std::end` do not return the ranges of an array that has decayed to a pointer type. All they see is a pointer. Informally, they don't know that the pointer actually points to the first element in an array.

It's your job to either pass a C++ standard library *container* like a `std::vector` to your function, perhaps by reference, or pass the length of the array as a parameter: for example

```
void possiblepermutation(int* array , std::size_t n){
    std::set<int> roots(array, array + n);
```

Comment: To the function, it is irrelevant if an array has decayed. All it knows is the parameter is a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Indeed, that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Updated question @Bathsheba

Comment: @Sumeet: Updated answer!